# How to: From service to factory, or a service without $scope in it?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular app where I am displaying the posts of a WP account, I am using `$scope`in the service but according to some articles, putting `$scope` in a service is not a proper way.

And also someone ask me to do a factory instead.

I am trying to not use `$scope` and to create a factory but my app goes down once I try.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7wdPJcszLBHWI8Kvg2l?p=preview) where I recreate the full action of my app.

And here part of the code you will see in that Plunker

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope,
                                 FreshlyPressed, $stateParams) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();
})

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $scope.postsURL = 'http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
      $http.jsonp($scope.postsURL).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        console.log(angular.toJson($scope.posts, 'pretty'));
      }).error(function(data, status_headers, config) {
          console.log('error')
      });
    },
    getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/'+ postId;
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
})

.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $sce, FreshlyPressed) {

    var postId = $stateParams.postId,

    FreshlyPressed.getPostById(postId).success(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       $scope.post = response;
    });

    // Marks src as safe
    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(src);
    };
});
```

so there you can see `.service('FreshlyPressed')` thats what I want to use as a Factory, or could be the same service but without the usage of `$scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PostDetailCtrl` and `FreshlyPressed.getPostById` is the right way. Here's how you'd modify `getBlogs` and `NewsCtrl`:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, FreshlyPressed, $stateParams) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs().success(function(blogs) {
      $scope.posts = blogs;
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }).error(function() {
      console.log('error');
    });
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();
})


.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function() {
      return $http.jsonp('http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK');
    },
    getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/'+ postId;
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: and how should I set a promise here ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'set a promise'?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you didn't understand well the reason why you create factories, so I'll begin my post describing factories.

A factory is a part of your app that should get an information for you, like a server side helper class. It shouldn't know whether it works for another factory, a provider, or a controller. For example, here you should create a function which returns the Promise* or the information for the web service.

My suggestion for you is to refactor according to this:

```js
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope,
                                 $ionicLoading,
                                 FreshlyPressed, $stateParams) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs().success(function(res){
      $scope.posts=angular.toJson(res);
    });
    
    /*Your'e here broadcasting to no one. you should broadcast to $rootScope.. so all the inheritant scopes  will get the messege.. and i can't see here the listening event either.*/
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  /*Initializing the posts*/
  $scope.doRefresh();
})

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function() {
      var postsURL = 'http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
      return $http.jsonp(postsURL);
    },
    getPostById: function(postId) {
      var url ='http://urbanetradio.com/wp-json/posts/'+ postId;
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
})

.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $sce, FreshlyPressed) {
  var postId = $stateParams.postId,
  siteId = $stateParams.siteId;
  console.log( $stateParams);

  FreshlyPressed.getPostById(postId).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    $scope.post = response;
  });

  // Marks src as safe
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(src);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```